# Conditional selection from a table Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns value, id, h (hierarchy) and date columns. A snapshot of it looks like this:

```
value | id  | h  | date 
---   |---  |--- |------------
 1.0  | 32  | 0  | Jul 3, 2017
 5.6  | 54  | 1  | Jul 2, 2017
 3.5  | 178 | 2  | Jul 3, 2017
 3.4  | 178 | 2  | Jul 1, 2017
```

This table has no primary key (aka there are multiple records for each value, id, h, or date). id and h have one to one relationship.

I want to write a query so that assuming today is Jul 3, it will return a value for each id for today, ordered by h, and showing null value if there is no record for today for that id. aka like this

```
value | id  | h  
---   |---  |--- 
 1.0  | 32  | 0  
 null | 54  | 1  
 3.5  | 178 | 2
```

Comment: If you want to see all of the `July 3rd` values, why is a `July 2nd` value present in the desired resultset?

Comment: In addition to all of the July 3rd values, I also want to see what are the other id's that don't have a value available today. I am showing null for that id 54, and not showing July 2nd value.

Comment: What about the row with Jul 1, 2017?  Why is it not in the result set with a `null` for value?

Comment: Because for that id 178 there is a value for today. I am only showing null for the id's that doesn't have a value today.

Comment: Ah; I didn't notice there was another 178 in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a left join might help :-

```
Select b.value,a.id,a.h
from 
(Select distinct id,h 
from <table>) a 
left join
(Select id,h,value 
from <table> where date > trunc(SYSDATE)) b
on a.id = b.id
and a.h = b.h;
```

Comment: I was using left join before and it didn't give me the whole table on the left back. Looking at your answer I realized I should put all the conditions in the parenthesis instead of at the end. Thank you this is solved!

Comment: In that case, please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement conditional `IF-ELSE` logic using [`CASE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/CASE-Expressions.htm) statement for the first column:

```
  select 
        // if current date is the same as date in date_col output value
     case when sysdate - date_col < 1 then value
        // else output null
     else null end "value", 
     id, h
  from my_table
  order by 3; // sort by h column
```

Answer (score 0):

Using analytical function, and case statements, you can achieve the result. Assuming that column h is never going to have a negative value, here is the query:

```
SQL> WITH cte_sample(value,id,h,D) AS (
  2   SELECT 1.0, 32, 0, to_date('Jul 18, 2017', 'Mon DD, YYYY') FROM dual UNION ALL
  3   SELECT  5.6, 54, 1, to_date('Jul 17, 2017', 'Mon DD, YYYY')  FROM dual UNION ALL
  4   SELECT 3.5, 178, 2, to_date('Jul 18, 2017', 'Mon DD, YYYY')  FROM dual UNION ALL
  5   SELECT 3.4, 178, 2, to_date('Jul 16, 2017', 'Mon DD, YYYY')  FROM dual UNION ALL
  6   SELECT 3.6, 178, 3, to_date('Jul 18, 2017', 'Mon DD, YYYY')  FROM dual ),
  7  ----------------------
  8  -- End of data
  9  ----------------------
 10  extracted_table AS (
 11  SELECT CASE WHEN d = trunc(sysdate) THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END AS VALUE,
 12         ID,
 13         h,
 14         d,
 15         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN d = trunc(SYSDATE) THEN -9 ELSE h END) rn
 16    FROM cte_sample)
 17  SELECT VALUE, ID, h FROM extracted_table WHERE rn = 1;
```

Output:

```
     VALUE         ID          H
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         32          0
                   54          1
       3.5        178          2
```